# Java crop and draw image using getsubimage

Tags: java, image, crop, drawimage

In the main class I'm drawing graphics objects like so:

```
//FIELDS
double FPS = 1000 / 60;
BufferStrategy bs;
public String ip; 
private int cx = 0;
private Hero h;
private TileMap map;
private int speed = 12;



public mainCla (){

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    h = new Hero("Hero/res/hero.png",100,50);
    map = new TileMap ("Hero/res/jun.png");


}


private void draw() {
        bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawImage(h.hi, h.hx, h.hy, this);
    g.fillOval(cx, 200, 40, 40);

    bs.show();

}
```

Then in another class, I've set the cropping of the loaded image like so:

```
public class TileMap {

//FIELDS
public String livpath;
BufferedImage mappa;
public int imgmapwidth;
public int imgmapheight;


public TileMap (String livpath ){
    this.livpath = livpath;
    BuildBlock();
    try {
        mappa = ImageIO.read (new File (livpath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

public void BuildBlock () {
    for (int x = 0; x < 128; x++)
        { for (int y = 0; y < 128; y++) {
        mappa.getSubimage (0,0,x,y);
        }       
        }
}
```

After that, I've tried to draw the extracted tile with g.drawimage from the main class(obviously I've created an instance with the path of the image, as requested by the constructor) but the image itself is not showing. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What are you using as the imageobserver?

Comment: "this" referring to the main class. I must say that other non cropped images show up as intended.

Comment: 'this' would refer to the imageobserver interface and not the main class. BufferedImage itself implements imageobserver so you should set the imageobserver to null. Maybe that will fix it since from what I can see it otherwise looks fine.

Comment: g.drawImage(map.mappa, 0,0,getX(),getY(),null);  doesn't work. It says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at game.TileMap.BuildBlock(TileMap.java:43)
 at game.TileMap.<init>(TileMap.java:31)
 at game.MainC.<init>(Main.java:34)

Comment: Hopefully this could help you; it's how I load my tiled map: http://pastebin.com/iCMLU5GN